# After Uninstalling MAMP, the favicon still displays in the browser. How do I remove it?

Tags: localhost, mamp

I had installed MAMP for a little while, and now even after uninstalling, the little elephant favicon still displays by default when I use any other server on localhost. Not only that, but the HTML page I had set for MAMP when accessing localhost is still being served.

How do I go about removing these completely from my computer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush your browser cache and restart apache.

To flush the browser cache in chrome:

1. Open dev tools
2. Right click the refresh icon
3. Select 'Empty cache and hard reload'

To restart apache on Mac OSX 10.10:

1. Open terminal
2. Run `sudo apachectl restart`